# increasing log level to catch issues

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, httpd, debugging, segmentation-fault

How do you increase the log level for apache to add coredumpdirectory and to catch any segfaults. I am trying to debug some issues and need apache to log every little bit of activitiy.

Comment: put the loglevel at "debug" it's described in apache documentation iirc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to modify the LogLevel directive in the config file for that virtual host. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#loglevel for more detail.